# ERROR: Error: Invalid protocol: null while running functions start in node js in OS X

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

kurian.john$ functions start

Google Cloud Functions Emulator RUNNING
ERROR: Error: Invalid protocol: null

```
at Request.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/request/request.js:460:31)
at new Request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/request/request.js:130:8)
at request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)
at DefaultTransporter.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:58:10)
at Discovery.discoverAPI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/googleapis/lib/discovery.js:261:19)
at GoogleApis.discoverAPI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/node_modules/googleapis/lib/googleapis.js:182:13)
at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:98:14)
at RestClient.getService (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:90:12)
at RestClient._action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:31:17)
at RestClient.listFunctions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/client/rest-client.js:131:17)
```

---

---

##

Comment: npm install worked , google emulator also installed

Comment: Hi Kurian, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better help you.